# JavaScript get object property value when the name is in a string

Tags: javascript

If know that this should work:

```
var object = {
  property: "value"
}
var propertyname = "property";
var propertyvalue = object[propertyname];
```

But how can I get the property value using the propertyname-variable when the object looks like this?

```
var object = {
  anotherObject: {
    property: "value"
  }
}
var propertyname = "anotherobject.property";
var propertyvalue = object[propertyname]; // This should not work...
```

**Edit:** As suggested, in this case the propertyname could be split on ".". But what if it is an arbitrary levels. Could I construct a for-loop somehow that could get the property-value?

Comment: Split the property name on the `.` character, then repeatedly get the property value using the successive elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's code doesn't work because there is no property with the name `anotherObject.property` in `object`. There's a property named `anotherObject`, and its value is an object with a property named `property`. To get to this, you have to access these successive levels of properties.

This code splits up the composite property name, and then performs the successive property accesses.

```
var nameArray = propertyname.split('.');
var propertyvalue = object;
for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    propertyvalue = propertyvalue[nameArray[i]];
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I need. Thanks! Not allowed to accept answer yet though...

Comment: Could you please explain exactly why your code works? Why doesn't the OP's work, but yours does? Please see [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/237685).